# Implication of group property $\phi(t_0;x_0)=\phi(t_1,y_0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, terminology, proof-explanation

Say we have the (vector) differential equation $\dot x=F(x)$, and all conditions apply such that the uniqueness and existence theorems apply. And say we have $\phi(t_0;x_0)=\phi(t_1;y_0)$ (where $\phi(t;x)$ is the flow of the differential equation. My book says that by the group property, we have $y_0=\phi(t_0-t_1;x_0)$. I don't understand how they arrive at this equation.

I know that if we have $x_1=\phi(t_1;x_0)$, that it holds that
$$
\phi(t+t_1;x_0)=\phi(t;x_1)=\phi(t;\phi(t_1;x_0)).
$$
This is what my book calls the group property, so I'm guessing I should be able to get $y_0=\phi(t_0-t_1;x_0)$ from that. However, I don't know how.

Say we set $\phi(t_0;x_0)=\phi(t_1;y_0)=x_1$.
Then we have
$$
\phi(t+t_0;x_0)=\phi(t;x_1)=\phi(t+t_1;y_0).
$$
I'm stuck here. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

First note that $t_0 = t_1 + (t_0 - t_1)$. Applying the group property we obtain
$$
\phi(t_0; x_0) = \phi\bigl(t_1; \phi(t_0 - t_1; x_0)\bigr)
$$
However, we also have 
$$
\phi\bigl(t_1; y_0\bigr) = \phi(t_0; x_0)
$$
so
$$
\phi\bigl(t_1; y_0\bigr) = \phi\bigl(t_1; \phi(t_0 - t_1; x_0)\bigr).
$$
You now have to assume some sort of invertibility to conclude that $y_0 = \phi(t_0 - t_1;x_0)$. (You didn't state the precise assumptions, so you should check this for yourself).

Comment: "Assume some sort of invertibility"? Hm, I guess, but it can be done quick and direct as follows: $y_0=\phi(0;y_0)=\phi(-t_1;\phi(t_1,y_0))=\phi(-t_1;\phi(t_0,x_0))=\phi(t_0-t_1;x_0)$.